# `sequel` orm fails when a string value is passed in a hash in `where` clause

Tags: ruby, sequel

I don't have idea what's going on when I use `.where(:status_name => 'Active')` instead of `.where("status_name = 'Active'")` it also happens when I use a string variable instead of harcode the 'Active' string

```
[1] pry(#<DefenseFeature>)> @db[:defense_status_tbl].select(:defense_status_id).where(:status_name => 'Active').single_record
Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError: Mysql2::Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61)
from /Users/calopez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/mysql2-0.3.17/lib/mysql2/client.rb:70:in `connect'
[2] pry(#<DefenseFeature>)> @db[:defense_status_tbl].select(:defense_status_id).where("status_name = 'Active'").single_record
=> {:defense_status_id=>2}
```

Showing sql query generate:

```
[3] pry(#<DefenseFeature>)> @db[:defense_status_tbl].select(:defense_status_id).where(:status_name => 'Active')
=> #<Sequel::Mysql2::Dataset:0x3fc29dcc5d2c>
[4] pry(#<DefenseFeature>)> @db[:defense_status_tbl].select(:defense_status_id).where("status_name = 'Active'")
=> #<Sequel::Mysql2::Dataset: "SELECT `defense_status_id` FROM `defense_status_tbl` WHERE (status_name = 'Active')">
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is if this use of the `where` clause is wrong: `.where(:status_name => 'Active')`, why it does not work, assuming status_name is a column on that table of course

Comment: `:status_name => 'Active'` is the standard used in the docs and what I always use. What version of Sequel and the MySQL gem are you using? For the best answer, use the Sequel IRC channel. The author monitors that and is extremely responsive and helpful.